# Transform a data.frame into a hierarchically organized array using dplyr in r

Tags: arrays, dplyr, split, tibble, hierarchical

I have a data.frame with thousands of rows and 6 columns, I would like to make an array hierarchically organized according to 5 columns.

Here's the a sample of my data:

```
YEAR<-rep(c(2016,2017), 10)
BIOME<-c(rep("AM",8),rep("AF",8), rep("AF",4))
PROJECT<- c(rep("Gurupi",4), rep("Juruena",4),rep("Veracel",4),rep("Ipanema",4),rep("Caima",4))
PLACE<-c(rep("Gu.1",2),rep("Gu.2",2),rep("Ju.1",2),rep("Ju.2",2),rep("Ve.1",2),rep("Ve.2",2),rep("Ip.1",2),rep("Ip.2",2),rep("Ca.1",2),rep("Ca.2",2))
SP<-rep(c("sp.1", "sp.2"), 10)
AB<-rep(3:2,10)
DATA<-as.data.frame(cbind(BIOME, PROJECT, YEAR, PLACE, SP, AB))
```

I´d like to create an array of 5 dimensions, with the first two dimensions being the PLACE (rows) and SP (columns) and AB being the SP values (abundance), a third dimension being the YEAR, a fourth dimension being the PROJECT and the fifth dimension being the BIOME.

An object that would look something like this

```
ARRAY[PLACE,SP,YEAR,PROJECT,BIOME]
```

Where the data.frames are organized by PLACES (rows) sampling the AB of several SP (columns) for each YEAR, hierarchically organized within the same PROJECT and within the same BIOME.

I'm paralyzed by this and any help will be very welcome.

best wishes

I tried to split data and after transform each list object in arrays, but I couldn´t provide de hierarchy order on it.

Comment: Hey. I am not sure what exactly you need. You have your data frame with some variables. each observation (row) has a value in either of these variables (year, etc..). Could you clarify what you need further? Not sure what else other than your data frame is needed to contain these dimensions

Comment: Hi Ricardo! Welcome to SO. A couple of pointers: 1. If at all possible, include data in your question, not screenshots, as there are lots of people who use the site who are vision impaired, 2. what data type do you want your output to be? Presumably if you have 5 factors your arrays are going to be very large and (mostly) very empty

Comment: Dear @RYann you for your comments. I've made my question clearer and added a code to create a sample of my data. As my original data.frame has thousands of rows I'm looking for a function that does something similar to what I want automatically. Any help is welcome

Comment: Dear @Mark I have provided a code in my question, any help is welcome.